# HTML Table Manipulation(multiple rows/cols in one <tr> or <td>)

Tags: html

I am making a form for inserting recipes to my database, whenever im dealing with forms, i always go for simplicity -> tables.

For example i have this code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <tr>Text:</tr>
            <tr>
                <input type="button" />
            </tr>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I wanted to have 2 rows inside a column, The above code doesnt actually work, im just demonstrating on how i would like it to arrange.

Is there anyway to do this? or do i have to resort to using divs and CSS(ugghh,, i hate this part. trial and error on the location.....)

Comment: Your markup is invalid you can't have elements directly in `<tr>`

Comment: just put another table (with 2 rows) inside your td

Comment: How is a table more simple for this task than using a list?

Comment: How about a simple `<br>` to have two lines?

Comment: @user1336827 i havent tried that, but wouldnt that mess with the table?

Comment: no ... tables can be nested without problems

Comment: @DavidThomas since im inputting ingredients, i was thinking of adding a button under the [Ingredients:][textboxhere]

That will use jquery to dynamically add textbox.

Comment: @user3024497 nope, you can have as many tables within tables as you like.

Comment: alternatively you can use colspan and rowspan attributes to join cells and keep everything in one table.

Comment: @DarrenCrabb do you mean, can't be nested without problems?

Comment: @user1336827 as one user stated, would it affect how i would grab the values within those tables or how i could interact with buttons or other types[radio,checkboxes].

Im weighing my choices, coz i might just do divs

Comment: no it would not affect your inputs.

Comment: Sounds more simpler than having to do CSS on divs though, although base on code integrity.. is it a good practice to nest tables?

Comment: sure, if it suits your needs.  Its perfectly fine markup.

Comment: I just found out it slows down loading time of the webpage. The best solution would be to use rowspan and colspan. Thanks though!

Comment: @user3024497, no, I mean tables can be nested without problems.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's no longer best practice to use tables for anything other than tabular content, DIVs and CSS should be used instead. There are things you used to be able to do with tables that you still can't achieve that easily without using them, such as certain 100% height issues. However, working with DIVs once you are used to them is a lot cleaner, more lightweight and a heck of a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr>
               <td>Text:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td><input type="button" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" />
    </td>
</tr>
```